# How to grep a variable which stores a full text file and print matching lines

Tags: perl

Hi I have been trying to execute a code where i used a variable $logs to save all my linux logs. 
Now i want to grep the variable for a pattern and print the whole line for the lines that have the pattern in them. 
I want to print whole line where i do grep /pattern/ and the lines that have pattern in them have to be printed. 
Anyways here is my code.

```
my $logs = $ssh->exec("cat system_logs");
my $search = "pattern";

if(grep($search,$logs))
{
    # this is where i want to print the lines matched.
    # I want to print the whole line what command to use?
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: thanks mu. sorry. forgot to edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (grep(/$search/, split(/\n/, $logs))) {
    print $_."\n";
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. it prints all the lines thats matched and also thats not matched. confused :O

Comment: I just made a minor correction to the way the search pattern is specified. Try that.

Comment: Don't forget to escape search pattern.